# unable to persist entity in spring tests with JpaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to persist an entity using. My test case works (data are persisted in db) when I handle my transaction myself.

```
public User saveUser(User user) {
    getEm().getTransaction().begin();
    getEm().persist(user);
    getEm().getTransaction().commit();      
    return user;
}
```

(entity manager comes from a template class which my DAO class extends)

It stops persisiting data when I configure spring to handle transactions.

test-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="domainPU" />
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.5.111/testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sdgdsgs" />
        <property name="password" value="sdfgdsg" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory">
            <ref local="entityManagerFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

UsersRepositoryTest:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:test-context.xml", "classpath:module-context.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
public class UsersRepositoryTest extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"findUserByLogin"})
    public void registerUser() throws DataAccessException {
        User myUser = getUserHomer();
        usersRepository.saveUser(myUser);

        User returnedUser = usersRepository.getUserByLogin(myUser.getLogin());

        assertNotNull(returnedUser);
                ...
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'domainPU'
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.6.Final}
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: domainPU
    ...]
2012-10-22 08:26:26 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'entityManagerFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'hibernateTranslator' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5c28305d: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,entityManagerFactory,dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,hibernateTranslator,usersDao,zoneDao,usersRepository,zoneRepository,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener startNewTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@3341b736]; rollback [false]
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_, user0_.active as active0_, user0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, user0_.email as email0_, user0_.last_login_date as last5_0_, user0_.login as login0_, user0_.password as password0_, user0_1_.AVATAR as AVATAR1_, user0_1_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_1_, user0_1_.ID as ID1_, user0_1_.LAST_NAME as LAST4_1_, case when user0_1_.id is not null then 1 when user0_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_ from user user0_ left outer join client user0_1_ on user0_.id=user0_1_.id where user0_.login=?
Hibernate: select phone0_.id as id2_0_, phone0_.phone_number as phone2_2_0_, phone0_.user_id as user3_2_0_ from phone phone0_ where phone0_.id=?
Hibernate: select address0_.ID as ID6_0_, address0_.apartment_number as apartment2_6_0_, address0_.city as city6_0_, address0_.country as country6_0_, address0_.house_number as house5_6_0_, address0_.post_code as post6_6_0_, address0_.street as street6_0_ from address address0_ where address0_.ID=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_, user0_.active as active0_, user0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, user0_.email as email0_, user0_.last_login_date as last5_0_, user0_.login as login0_, user0_.password as password0_, user0_1_.AVATAR as AVATAR1_, user0_1_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_1_, user0_1_.ID as ID1_, user0_1_.LAST_NAME as LAST4_1_, case when user0_1_.id is not null then 1 when user0_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_ from user user0_ left outer join client user0_1_ on user0_.id=user0_1_.id where user0_.login=?
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener endTransaction
INFO: Committed transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@63edf84f testClass = UsersRepositoryTest, testInstance = pl.eports.zonen.user.repository.UsersRepositoryTest@7e3bc473, testMethod = findUserByLogin@UsersRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1c493dca testClass = UsersRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:test-context.xml, classpath:module-context.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]]
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener startNewTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (2): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@3341b736]; rollback [false]
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_, user0_.active as active0_, user0_.creation_date as creation3_0_, user0_.email as email0_, user0_.last_login_date as last5_0_, user0_.login as login0_, user0_.password as password0_, user0_1_.AVATAR as AVATAR1_, user0_1_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_1_, user0_1_.ID as ID1_, user0_1_.LAST_NAME as LAST4_1_, case when user0_1_.id is not null then 1 when user0_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_ from user user0_ left outer join client user0_1_ on user0_.id=user0_1_.id where user0_.login=?
2012-10-22 08:26:27 org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener endTransaction
INFO: Committed transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@63edf84f testClass = UsersRepositoryTest, testInstance = pl.eports.zonen.user.repository.UsersRepositoryTest@7e3bc473, testMethod = registerUser@UsersRepositoryTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1c493dca testClass = UsersRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:test-context.xml, classpath:module-context.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]]
PASSED: findUserByLogin
FAILED: registerUser
java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
        ...
```

As you can see from the stacktrace, transaction seems to be started and finished, but no sql inserts are produced and no data are inserted into db (data rollback is set to false)

I've tried force flushing data after persist() but spring managed transaction seems to be finished by then.

I've looked for a similar issue on forums but none works.
I can provide some more code if necessary.

I'm using Spring 3.1.2 and Hibernate 4.1.6.Final

**update:**

DAO: (@Transactional annotation is put here instead on service layer temporarily)

```
@Repository
public class JpaUsersDAO extends JpaDAOTemplate<User> implements UsersDAO {

public JpaUsersDAO(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    super(factory.createEntityManager(), User.class);
}

    @Transactional
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        getEm().persist(user);  
        return user;
    }
}
```

DAOTemplate:

```
public abstract class JpaDAOTemplate<T extends Serializable> {

    private EntityManager em;

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public JpaDAOTemplate(EntityManager em, final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.em = em;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    public T getById(Integer id) {...}
    ...
}
```

bean definition:

```
<bean id="usersDao"
    class="pl.package.user.dao.impl.JpaUsersDAO">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

It seems that the transaction is lost somewhere after selects and before calling getEm().persist() - **org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl#tx is null** when calling persist() but it was **org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JDBCTransaction** before the call (when sql select statements calls were made)

**update 2**
debug level stacktrace:

```
[2012-10-23 11:15:14,546]DEBUG 38629[main] - org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:365) - Creating new transaction with name [registerUser]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
[2012-10-23 11:15:33,252]DEBUG 57335[main] - org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:316) - Opened session at timestamp: 13509837332
[2012-10-23 11:15:33,252]DEBUG 57335[main] - org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:368) - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@18025c5c] for JPA transaction
[2012-10-23 11:15:40,085]DEBUG 64168[main] - org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:158) - begin
[2012-10-23 11:15:40,101]DEBUG 64184[main] - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:295) - Obtaining JDBC connection
[2012-10-23 11:15:40,101]DEBUG 64184[main] - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:301) - Obtained JDBC connection
[2012-10-23 11:15:40,101]DEBUG 64184[main] - org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:69) - initial autocommit status: true
[2012-10-23 11:15:40,101]DEBUG 64184[main] - org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:71) - disabling autocommit
[2012-10-23 11:16:06,934]DEBUG 91017[main] - org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:407) - Not exposing JPA transaction [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@18025c5c] as JDBC transaction because JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@5f343722] does not support JDBC Connection retrieval
[2012-10-23 11:16:06,934]DEBUG 91017[main] - org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.isRollback(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:357) - No method-level @Rollback override: using default rollback [false] for test context [[TestContext@5809fdee testClass = UsersRepositoryTest, testInstance = pl.eports.zonen.user.repository.UsersRepositoryTest@3fde891b, testMethod = registerUser@UsersRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@77fe4169 testClass = UsersRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:test-context.xml, classpath:module-context.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]]
[2012-10-23 11:16:06,934] INFO 91017[main] - org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:275) - Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@37977909]; rollback [false]
[2012-10-23 11:17:08,103]DEBUG152186[main] - org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
[2012-10-23 11:17:08,118]DEBUG152201[main] - org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:106) - Adding transactional method 'saveUser' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
[2012-10-23 11:17:08,118]DEBUG152201[main] - org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'txManager'
[2012-10-23 11:17:27,073]DEBUG171156[main] - org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doGetTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:331) - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@18025c5c] for JPA transaction
[2012-10-23 11:18:04,031]DEBUG208114[main] - org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:470) - Participating in existing transaction
```

**Final update:**

Problem was in the way I injected EntityManagerFactory to my DAO. I used applicationContext.xml configuration file to inject it (this way EMF does not participate in transaction). To have it working I changed my DAO class to:

```
@Repository
public class JpaUsersDAO extends JpaDAOTemplate<User> implements UsersDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Spring 3.0`. 
I am not clear your coding `public User saveUser(User user)` method. Even If you use `Spring 3.0`, you handel the transaction your self(`Bean Management Transaction`).
It just need to use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` annotation. Change `propagation` type based on your process.

**Example DAO :**

GroupDAO.java

```
@Repository("GroupDAO")
public class GroupDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void insert(Group group) {
        try {
            em.persist(group);
            em.flush();
        } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
        }
    }
}
```

spring-bean.xml with `EclipseLink JPA` <-- just for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xmlns:int-security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/security/spring-integration-security-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="your-package"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.5.111/testdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="your-username"/>
        <property name="password" value="your-password"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<!--        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>-->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="domainPU"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <props>
                <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform"/>
<!--        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />-->
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: The @Transactional annotation is placed on the DAO method (you can see that transaction is opened from the stacktrace I've provided). You don't have to specify the propagation type because Propagation.REQUIRED is the default.

Comment: @aurban `Propagation.REQUIRED` is default. you are right. I just show example. Submit full code of your DAO class

Comment: I've missed that you're using '@PersistenceContext' annotation in your example. I was just injecting it in my application-context.xml - that way it doesn't participate in transaction. When I changed it to use '@PersistenceContext' it started working. Thanks!